# Hive query performance issue

Tags: performance, hadoop, concurrency, hive

I am facing below performance issue with hadoop hive.

1. Extreme slowness while connecting from multiple reducers concurrently.
2. Are there any limitations on `Hive` in regards to how many `Clients` request `Hive` can serve at one time? If yes, how can we control/tune that in a cluster environment
3. Slowness while performing select statement. It might be related to previous points

Comment: Generally, recursive MapReduce (as implied by querying Hive from within a Reducer) easily overloads clusters. Is it just the speed of making the initial connection to Hive that worries you, or the query time?

Comment: There can be many limits, usually the DB connections for the metastore are the first thing that run out. But as @AlexanderGessler already says, it is mostly because you are misusing Hive badly.

Comment: Thank you guys for your reply. @ Alexander Initial connection doesn't take much time it's the query time. When I run the same hive query locally it runs really fast, as expected, but when I run it on the server side it takes long time, the jdbc request response is really slow.